# How do you code a div element in html to be a link?

Tags: html

I am trying to create a div element, that when you click it, the div will bring you to a website. My code is below:

```html
<div class="clickme">
<p>Click me to go to somesite.com</p>
<p>Dummy text...................</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrap the div in a  element

Shown below...

```html
<a href="somesite.com">
<div class="clickme">
<p>click me to goto somesite.com</p>
<p>DUMMY TEXT...........</p>
</div>
</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

While wrapping a `<div>` with an `<a>` possible, it's not common.

Most of the time JS is being used, listing to a click event, since the action required is not redirecting to a different page, but to trigger an action without redirecting or including more logic than redirecting.